How to fix 'Errors during XML parse' in Unity with Vuforia?
enter image description hereI am working on a Unity project using Vuforia Engine to implement AR functionality. I encountered an issue where Unity shows the following error in the console:
Errors during XML parse: System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
This error appears after I added some Vuforia ImageTargets. I have ensured that the .xml and .dat files are in the StreamingAssets/Vuforia folder.
Unity version: 2022.3.37f1
Vuforia SDK version: 10.28.4
Platform: Windows 10
I have tried the following:
Verified that the .xml and .dat files are correctly placed in the StreamingAssets/Vuforia folder.
Checked the Vuforia Configuration in Unity to ensure the database is enabled.
Reinstalled Vuforia Engine through the Unity Package Manager.
None of these steps resolved the issue, and the error persists. I was expecting Unity to correctly load the Vuforia database and detect my ImageTargets.

Have you examined the xml files to ensure they have correct content?

"Yes, I have examined the XML files, and the content appears to be correct. Each  entry includes a name and size attribute as expected. For example:
xml







The XML files are located in the following directory:
D:\Project\AR\Application\Assets\StreamingAssets\Vuforia\

This page contains information on how to debug an app. I would suggest you collect some log to see if you get some hint of what might be the problem https://developer.vuforia.com/library/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-your-app#collect-logs

Are you running in playmode on Windows 10 or are you trying to deploy and application to that platfrom?
